# How can i print summary of ridge regression, lasso regression, and elastic net on python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I am trying to see summary of Reg(ridge, lasso, elastic net.)
not like R, python is still hard to me.

I found how I print summary of OLS by this code

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import statsmodels.api as sm
X2 = sm.add_constant(X_train)
est = sm.OLS(y_train, X2)
est2 = est.fit()
print(est2.summary())
```

but how can I print ridge, lasso, elastic net regression like OLS??